# white color Issue after create thumbnail image in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-extension

I am creating thumbnail image in yii2, It is working fine for me, but there is issue with image, when i create thumbnai it is not transperent,I used this function to create thumbani

```
$itemImage=Image::thumbnail( $commonthumb, 150, 150,\Imagine\Image\ManipulatorInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET)->save($createthumb, ['quality' => 100])
```

I used `THUMBNAIL_INSET` and `THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND` both but not getting clear image with result,I can't used `THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND` becauase it is crop that image, so i used `THUMBNAIL_INSET` it is good but it is not transperent, So how can i solve this issues ? Can anyone please help to solve this issue

Comment: It should work, is your original image transparent ? gif or png ?